# Set Object Key/Value pair after a list item has been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set an Object property equal to the value of a clicked list item (0, 1, 2, 3).  I am able to console.log the correct value, but the object property is not being set.

Could someone please explain how to set my gameObject property to the correct list item value?

```js
var gameObject = {
  questions: [
    {
      title: "What color is the sky?",
      answers: [
        "blue",
        "green",
        "red",
        "purple"
      ],
      correctAnswer: 0,
      userSelection: ''
    },
    {
      title: "What color is UNC blue?",
      answers: [
        "Duke blue",
        "Sky blue",
        "red",
        "purple"
      ],
      correctAnswer: 1,
      userSelection: ''
    },
    {
      title: "What color is UNC blue?",
      answers: [
        "Duke blue",
        "Sky blue",
        "red",
        "purple"
      ],
      correctAnswer: 1,
      userSelection: ''
    },
  ],
  currentQuestion: 0,
  userCorrect: 0,
  userIncorrect: 0,
  userBlank: 0,
  timer: 30,
  timerRunning: false
};

var triviaAnswerSection = $('#answers');

function renderGameAnswers() {
  var html = '';
  html += `<ul class='question'>`
  html += `<li class='answer' value='0'><a href='#'>${gameObject.questions[gameObject.currentQuestion].answers[0]}</a></li>`
  html += `<li class='answer' value='1'><a href='#'>${gameObject.questions[gameObject.currentQuestion].answers[1]}</a></li>`
  html += `<li class='answer' value='2'><a href='#'>${gameObject.questions[gameObject.currentQuestion].answers[2]}</a></li>`
  html += `<li class='answer' value='3'><a href='#'>${gameObject.questions[gameObject.currentQuestion].answers[3]}</a></li>`
  html += `</ul>`
  triviaAnswerSection.html(html);
  $('.answer').on('click', function() {
    var answer = $(this).attr('value');
    gameObject.questions[gameObject.currentQuestion].userSelection = answer;
  });
}

renderGameAnswers();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div id='game'>
  <div id='title'>
  </div>
  <div id='start'>
  </div>
  <div id='stop'>
  </div>
  <div id='timeRemaining'>
  </div>
  <div id='questions'>
  </div>
  <div id='answers'>
  <div id='done'>
  </div>
  <div id='userScore'>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you set gameObject.currentQuestion?

Comment: I set gameObject.currentQuestion equal to 0 in the actual gameObject.

Comment: @madalin ivascu - thanks for your reference.  I followed the post and changed my function accordingly with no luck.  Here's what I have now based on that post:  $('#answers').on('click', '.answer', function() {
    var answer = $(this).attr('value');
    gameObject.questions[gameObject.currentQuestion].userSelection = answer;
  });